# Form fields in table / two half block, navigation with "tab"

Tags: html, css, forms, navigation, css-tables

I currently have a "table" like following

```html
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 48%; vertical-align: top;">

<label>Firma</label>[text* firma]

<label>Telefon</label>[number telefon]

</div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 1%;"></div>
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 48%; vertical-align: top;">

<label>Name</label>[text* fullname]

<label>E-Mail</label>[email* email]

</div>
```

When I want to navigate through the different form fields with "tab" (Windows), it goes from top left to the one below that one. I want to move from left to right though, then top right, to left (below top left) again and so on. I couldn't find anything related to that. Do you have any hints?

Comment: I'm not too sure what the order is that you are trying to achieve. Do you mean how the items are laid out or the tabIndex?

Comment: They're laid out "correctly" (as I want), but the tabbing doesn't work. The tab should move from left to right, but instead it moves from top to bottom

Answer (score 1):

You can use tabindex attribute in your fields to do so.
Look at these links to know about tabindex,
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp
https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/08/using-the-tabindex-attribute/

Comment: Hmm, tried different tabindexes, but doesn't seem to work, see http://www.diecutterkollegen.de/test-2/ (click on pink button). When in first field, and hitting "tab", the cursor dissappears completely..

Comment: Hey, I have checked it. It's JETZT ANFRAGEN right. It's working fine. When I press tab it's pointing to the next field.

Comment: Hm, strange, not for me. And starting at the second row (which doesn't have a tabindex), with pressing tab it's only point to the field below it, not on the right.